# How to convert "weekday month day time" to datetime (YYYY-MM-DD)?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a column `fecha` formatted as a string in the form of

```
Mon Feb 22 07:55:55 CET 2021
```

How do I convert it to a date format like YYYY-MM-DD? I have tried `CAST`, `CONVERT` ...

And I always get the following error message:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: Will your date and time *always* be in the format `ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss tz yyyy`?

Comment: Is the day of month always 2 digits?

Comment: Yes, the format is always like this in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Assuming***, as I comment, the value is *always* `ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss tz yyyy` you could do some messy string manipulation to convert the value to a valid date and time data type. Then you can format the date however you want in your presentation layer, as it's strongly typed:

```sql
SELECT V.DateString,
       TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0),STUFF(STUFF(LEFT(STUFF(V.DateString,1,8,''),12),3,0,RIGHT(V.DateString,5)),3,0,SUBSTRING(V.DateString,4,4)),113) AS ConvertedDate
FROM (VALUES('Mon Feb 22 07:55:55 CET 2021'))V(DateString);
```

Of course, the real lesson here is don't store date and time values as a `varchar` in your database. Date and Time data types exist for a reason; use them.

Comment: This could be simplified as `TRY_CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(@DateTtimeString,5,7) + SUBSTRING(@DateTtimeString,25,4) , 109)`, if the day number is always 2 digits.

Comment: Depends if the OP wants to retain the time or not, @DanGuzman . As it's there, I *assumed* the OP would like to retain it. If they don't want to retain it, why are they storing it?

Comment: I would, however, suggest using `RIGHT` over `SUBSTRING` for obtaining the year, @DanGuzman , as some timezones aren't 3 characters and we don't know where that value is coming from. For example, Europe is observing DST at the moment, so a value for the same timezone *might* have `CEST` instead (Central European Summer Time) for a value for today.

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly, and yes, the format is always exactly like that (in this one table, at least...). And I do need the time. I thought I could do something like that, but I hoped some easier transformation was possible. And I will see if I can remake the table with this column as type date. Anyways, thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh yeah, I did see some CEST @Larnu. I'll take note to use `RIGHT`

Comment: My answer does use `RIGHT`, @Sergi , my comment was at Dan, as they don't in their comment.

Comment: I see now, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are standard functions to deal with your source strings, so I would combine simpler standard transformations to get that result :

```
declare @Cadena varchar(50) = 'Mon Feb 22 07:55:55 CET 2021'

select substring(@Cadena, 25, 4)  + '-' + 
       replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(substring(@Cadena, 5, 3), 'Jan', '01'), 'Feb', '02'), 'Mar', '03'), 'Apr', '04'), 'May', '05'), 'Jun', '06'), 'Jul', '07'), 'Aug', '08'), 'Sep', '09'), 'Oct', '10'), 'Nov', '11'), 'Dec', '12') + '-' +
       substring(@Cadena, 9, 2)
```

This will fail if your string are not always in the exact same format, in that case more code would be needed.